# Google analytics in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my app to track each pages. I am using article from http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/10/21/statistics-for-your-windows-phone-application-google-analytics. The problem is whenever I go to Content->overview in google analytics detail page I am getting values like Views/MainPage.xaml,View/Page1.xaml.

So my question is whether there is a way to change this pagename to custom names.

Comment: Hi, How was your experience with MSAF.GoogleAnalytics from Mark Monster? Did it work well for your app? I am making a windows phone app and trying to find out a good library to integrate Google analytics to my app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was good, but when you run marketplace testkit there are some issues in MSAF. Refer http://msaf.codeplex.com/workitem/17797 and http://msaf.codeplex.com/discussions/350885.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So what did you end up using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this manually by just dipping into the source code. A Page View is just a specific set of `AnalyticsEvent` property values sent so all I'm calling is.

```
Log(new AnalyticsEvent() {
    ActionValue = pageViewUri,
    HitType = Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Data.HitType.PageView,
    Name = "CurrentScreenChanged",
    NavigationState = pageViewUri,
    ObjectType = pageViewUri
});
```

Which is working how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can right click the page and select "Rename", then rename the pages to something sensible that makes sense.

Don't forget that you might have to change references to the pages in your code (if Visual Studio doesn't do that for you)